# C: File exist but won't open. Counting letters?

Tags: c, file, fopen

It's pretty stupid but I wrote some code yesterday to open a file. When I opened it today the file couldn't be found.
I didn't change anything. Does someone know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char ch, file_name[25];
    FILE *fp;

    //Text aufrufen
    printf("Welche Datei soll aufgerufenru werden?\n");
    gets(file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode

    //Existenztest
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Tatsächliche Ausgabe
    printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);

    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And: How can you count e.g. every single letter? (Appearance of each letter)

Comment: Your program doesn't remove the file. Maybe you made a typo entering the filename?

Comment: `file_name[25]` is pretty small.

Comment: *How can you count e.g. every single letter?*  [`isalpha()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.2)

Comment: It looks like this code was written in 1987.  That's the only possible reason for the usage of `gets`, and even then it was probably bad practice.  *Never* use `gets`

Answer (score 1):

I think your filename contains a whitespace which is not read by `gets` during runtime

Replace `gets(file_name);` with `scanf("%[^\n]", file_name);`

> And: How can you count e.g. every single letter?

You just have to declare a count variable and add some additional code inside your while loop:

```
unsigned count = 0;

while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)

{

    printf("%c", ch);
    if (isalpha(ch)) ++count; // isalpha can be found in ctype.h

}
```

Comment: `ch` needs to be an `int` value as that's what `fgetc()` returns.  As a `char`, it's impossible to reliably detect `EOF`